# Angular-Kendo Stacked charts with percentage formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

On the 100% Stacked Chart, I cannot get the valueAxis format property to render a full % amout from 0 to 100%.

Please see my plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2nvnbDSHAdaSpOeJbHzn?p=preview

You'll find it's a very simple example, with an index.html file and one script.js. The $scope.chartOptions object is assigned in script.js.

It is incorrectly displaying the percentage as :

```
0%     0.2%     0.4%    ...  1%
```

The html div is defined as follows:

```
<div kendo-chart k-options="chartOptions" k-rebind="chartOptions"></div>
```

I've read the online samples, and also read the Kendo docs at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-format.

And I've tried  `kendo.toString("{0}", "p")` to format it property, but can't get it.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/stacked100-bar

your help is appreciated.

thanks,
Bob

[image: kendo stacked chart]

Comment: Is your Plunker correct? I'm not seeing any percentages and it seems like a totally different graph

Comment: okay this one seems to be working - http://plnkr.co/edit/2nvnbDSHAdaSpOeJbHzn?p=preview

Comment: Sure I am checking it out now. I'm seeing correct percentages e.g. 20%, 40% etc. Does not look like the image provided. Am I missing the issue here?

Comment: the top three bars are the same (MTM, 1D VaR 99%, 10Day VaR 99%); however, in my posted image I'm showing that I have a problem in my dev environment. I may have introduced a bug in my code, seeing that the `chartOptions` object I've posted in the plunk is working fine ! thank you Sal !

Comment: cool sounds good. Keep me posted with what it was when you find it I'll be interested to hear

Comment: @salniro - it's my `"format": "{0}%"` property which is screwing up the Kendo percentage labels (search that in `script.js` file). If I totally REMOVE `"format"` property, Kendo takes care of the labels automatically. I guess that's because I'm wiring up a Kendo 100% Stacked Bar/Column chart.

Comment: see my two plunks http://plnkr.co/edit/2nvnbDSHAdaSpOeJbHzn?p=preview (BAD VERSION) , and http://plnkr.co/edit/USGYVogMytxbr8Xv0m5h?p=preview (GOOD VERSION)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per discussion and your identified issue, you don't necessarily need to remove `'format'`, but in your Plunker, `'format': '{0}%'` is not valid. If you change to the following, you can keep `format` and have the results you wish

See valid [Kendo Number Formatting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting) for more information

```
"valueAxis": {
     "labels": {
          "format": "p0",      /*or "p" to include decimals*/
              "rotation": -30
          },
          "line": {
              "visible": false
          },
          "axisCrossingValue": 0
      }
  }
```

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/baIAbJFNsqCwUdOiYUG6?p=preview)